# Parse an adaptive card json to C# object and dynamically build Action.Showcards based on my api data

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have an adaptive card json with Action.ShowCard property and 1 submit button. I want to convert it to C# object and loop the Action.showcard to dynamically build multiple showcard buttons based on the count/data coming from an api call.

I was able to convert it to c# object using "AdaptiveCard.FromJson(json).Card", but not able to proceed further

Suppose i get 3 project codes, so i want to build 3 action.showcards and populate its fields from api data.

Below is the adaptive card with only 1 showcard, I need to consume this card and build multiple showcards.

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "**Timesheet Project Codes**",
        "wrap": true
    },
    {
        "type": "ActionSet",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                "title": "123456",
                "card": {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Project Code:",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "123456",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Project Name:",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "abc/def/ghi",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Cost Code:",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "ghi1234",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Project Code Start Date:",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "January 1, 2022",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Project Code End Date: ",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "December 31, 2025",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Project Code Allocation Start Date:",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "March 1, 2022",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Project Code Allocation End Date:",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "November 31, 2022",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "ActionSet",
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Fill Timesheet",
                "data": "Fill Timesheet"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Are you having problems in de-serializing the above `JSON` output?

Comment: @RahulSharma No i can de-serialize. The problem is that after de-serializing i want to dynamically build the Adaptive show card. So here there is only 1 show card. But i want to create multiple showcards from C# code, each having different contents.

Comment: Why not create a proper `Model` for the above `JSON` and then de-serialize it to a `List<AdaptiveShowCard>` ? This will get all the content. If you can post your entire `JSON` output string, then we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation, I understand that you're using `AdaptiveCard.FromJson` to deserialize the entire thing into onc card.

Instead, you could try deserializing the JSON and then parsing it to build multiple separate Adaptive Cards [in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/authoring-cards/net#example-create-an-adaptivecard-and-serialize-to-json).

Once you have built C# objects from your parsed JSON, you can then manipulate them and add or remove components as desired.